# How to make vertical CCScrollView align to top?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a vertical CCScrollView on iOS where height is not divisible by cell height.

So, cells align to the bottom of CCScrollView.

Is there any way to make CCScrollView align to top?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the CCScrollView, but I have tried another UIScrollView implementation for cocos2d and I think the same way I solved this could apply. Set your scrollview's contentOffset to `ccp(0.0, scrollview.contentSize.height - scrollview.size.height)` instead of `ccp(0.0, 0.0)`. Then, adjust the position of your content based on your scrollview's contentSize. For instance if you wanted your content's position to be `ccp(x, y)` as it appears, you could do something like

`content.position = CGPointMake(x, scrollview.contentSize.height - scrollview.size.height + y)`

size is the view size of the scrollview, but I'm not sure what the actual property for scrollview is since I haven't used it.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved this problem changed `-[CCScrollView relocateContainer:]`. I guess it is not good to modify libraries but I think it is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code works for me:

`[self.scrollView setContentOffset:ccp(0, -self.scrollView.container.contentSize.height + self.scrollView.boundingBox.size.height) animated:NO];`